# Alternative of the imageDatastore function

Tags: matlab, machine-learning, computer-vision, deep-learning, object-recognition

I have been going through a tutorial of deep learning in MATLAB. I tried to execute the following code

```
rootFolder = 'E:/Data Science and Machine Learning Stuff/DataSets/scene_categories';
categories = {'bedroom'  ,  'CALsuburb'  ,  'industrial'   , 'kitchen' , 'livingroom','PARoffice','store'};
imds = imageDatastore(fullfile(rootFolder, categories),'LabelSource', 'foldernames');
tbl = countEachLabel(imds)
```

Executing the above code generates the following error:

```
Undefined function or variable 'imageDatastore'.
```

After doing a lot of research about the error I finally came to know that the function `imageDatastore` is introduced in **R2015b**.

My current MATLAB release is **R2015a**, so I do not have access to this function. I have also tried the `datastore` function that is present in this release (R2015a) but have had no luck.

Can anyone help in writing an alternative code for the `imageDatastore` function that performs the same function as `imageDatastore`; or can some tell me how to use the `datastore` function for this task.

Comment: @Adriaan I have edited the question

Comment: Thanks. I have removed the image altogether, as it's of no use now that you have actual code there and tidied up a bit further. Do let me know if I messed up somehow,